# Setting a custom center for a dialog in Angular Material

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I'm trying to fix the position of my dialog in Angular. I can set or update the position using the `DialogRef` object or the `MatDialogConfig` object. When I set the left position to 25px the dialog will appear 25 pixels from left. When I do not specify a position the dialog will always appear in the center. Unfortunately, I'm using a sidenav which is 250px wide. So I would like my dialog to be positioned at the center + 250px. How do I approach this problem?

```
const dialogConfig = new MatDialogConfig();
dialogConfig.autoFocus = true;
dialogConfig.disableClose = true;
const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(TCtor, dialogConfig);

dialogRef.updatePosition({ left: "25px" });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `calc`, a native css function to compute the left position of your dialog box. See [more details](https://css-tricks.com/a-couple-of-use-cases-for-calc/) about it.

The "less gracious" point is that you need to set the width of dialog box and use it also inside the `calc` computation.

> So I would like my dialog to be positioned at the center + 250px

2 possible interpretations :

#### 1) The left side of dialog box should be at center + 250px

- Middle of screen: `50vw` (50% of viewport width)

```js
this.dialog.open(DemoDialogComponent, {
  height: '200px',
  width: '400px',
  position: {
    left: 'calc(50vw + 250px)'
  }
});
```

#### 2) Dialog is centered, but with a shift of 250px at right

- Dialog box width: `400px`
- Middle of screen: `50vw` (50% of viewport width)

```js
this.dialog.open(DemoDialogComponent, {
  height: '200px',
  width: '400px',
  position: {
    left: 'calc(50vw - 200px + 250px)'
  }
});
```